# Обработка битового потока ( fragmented IP Protocol) с помощью Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ip, udp, wireshark

Есть высокоскоростной битовой поток. Он передает по сети на мой компьютер (IP-пакеты).

Часть пакетов большой длины, поэтому разбиваются на маленькие.

1. Пытался избавиться от фрагментации путем изменение MTU в настройках сетевой карты. Было установлено что пакеты не более 9 Кбайт. Данный вариант не захотел работать.
2. Сейчас пробую с помощью Delphi ловить битовый поток и склеивать на приемной стороне. Компоненты типа Indy UDPServer видят и принимают только пакеты с полноценным заголовком UDP, а фрагментированные не принимает.

Ниже представлен код события, в котором битовый поток принимается и записывается в файл. В последующем анализе фрагментированные пакеты не были найдены.

```
        procedure TForm3.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
        var
          Count:integer;
          Buf: array [0..8191] of byte;
        begin
          Count := High(Adata);
          CopyMemory(@Buf[0], @AData[0], Count);
          FileWrite(hndF, Buf, Count);
        end;
```

Какие есть решение данной ситуации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вопросе нет обьектов, которыми оперируют программисты (например кода программы или чего-то еще), мы вам не можем помочь.

Comment: Код - просто скинуть фрагмент на диск - ничего не дает. И если в файле *фрагментированные пакеты не были найдены* то нету способа сделать именно этот код рабочим.

Comment: Возможно в Delphi есть компонента, которая позволяет принимать "сырые" IP-пакеты? Еще вариант есть копать в сторону маршрутизатора (возможно он творит такие фрагменты).

Comment: Вы проверяли с помощью wireshark, что до серверной машины действительно долетают фрагментированные пакеты?

Comment: Избавиться от фрагментации UDP путем изменения MTU - не лучшая идея, т.к. на промежуточных узлах типа роутера/хаба MTU может отличаться. Википедия говорит, что единственный гарантированный способ избежать фрагментации - не отправлять более 508 байт в одном пакете.

Comment: Скриншот выше взят с Wireshark'а. Поэтому и пытаюсь пока что безуспешно решить задачу одним с двух способов: убрать фрагментацию или получить поток с фрагментацией с последующей обработкой. Доступа к устройству, которое формирует поток, у меня нету (длину пакета регулировать не могу).

Comment: Попробуйте обычный сокет или winapi или UDPSocket c VCL (если он там есть).

Comment: Вариант 1. Использовать TCP - он сам решает такие проблемы. Вариант 2. Реализовать свой протокол над UDP, который будет из фрагментов собирать нужные пакеты, причём придётся реализовать механизм обработки потерянных фрагментов.